# Split string by whitespaces removes new line characters

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I'm splitting a string by whitespaces, but for some reason the new line characters are being removed. For example:

```
String[] splitSentence = "Example sentence\n\n This sentence is an example".
   split("\\s+");
```

splitSentence will contain this:

```
["Example", "sentence", "This", "sentence", "is", "an", "example"]
```

and if I make this:

```
String[] splitSentence = "Example sentence\n\n This sentence is an example".
   split("\\s");
```

splitSentence will contain this:

```
["Example", "sentence", "", "", "This", "sentence", "is", "an", "example"]
```

---

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
["Example", "sentence\n\n", "This", "sentence", "is", "an", "example"]
```

Or like this:

```
["Example", "sentence", "\n", "\n", "This", "sentence", "is", "an", "example"]
```

I've tried a lot of things with no luck... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `\n` is also whitespace.

Comment: just change "\\s+" to " +"

Comment: If you want to exclude the newline from `\s` then use the inverse of the inverse and add `\n` like this `[^\S\n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regex, `\s` is defined to be equivalent to the characters in this set:

```
[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

(See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).  If you don't want newlines to be treated like spaces, then you can write your own set:

```
splitSentence = "Example sentence\n\n This sentence is an example".split("[ \t\\x0B\f\r]+");
```

(or eliminate other characters you don't want the `split` to recognize).

(`\t` is TAB, `\x0B` is vertical tab, `\f` is FF (form feed), `\r` is CR)

**EDIT:** This method seems to produce the second result you mentioned, where the `\n`'s are returned as separate strings:

```
splitSentence = "Example sentence\n\n This sentence is an example".split("[ \t\\x0B\f\r]+|(?=\n)");
```

This uses lookahead to split at a point that is immediately followed by `\n`, but doesn't treat `\n` as a delimiter that will be removed from the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] splitSentence = "Example sentence\n\n This sentence is an example".
   split(' ');
```

this version should work, so empty space will be remove only and not new line.

Answer (score 1):

Split by spaces and tabs (without newline):

```
String[] splitSentence = "Example sentence\n\n This sentence is an example".split("[ \t]+");
```

Result: `["Example", "sentence\n\n", "This", "sentence", "is", "an", "example"]`